# ruby using if inside loop with user input

Tags: ruby, loops, if-statement, user-input

I trying to make loop through if statement if user input is invalid it keep telling to enter number only  or break if true

I tried this is my code

```
class String
  def numeric?
    Float(self) != nil rescue false
  end
end
cond = false

puts "Enter number "
line = gets.chomp.strip

 while cond == false
    if (line.numeric?  )
        puts "Ok nice  "
        cond = true
        else 
        puts "Please enter number only  "

    end
 end
```

but it keep looping if the condition is false just printing "Please enter number only  "

i will be very happy for any suggestion

Thank you

Comment: You don't ask for another line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after telling the user to just enter a number you don't read another number, you just loop back around.

The easiest way to fix this is to move the prompt and input into the `while` loop, a bit like this:

```
class String
  def numeric?
    Float(self) != nil rescue false
  end
end
cond = false

 while cond == false
    puts "Enter number "
    line = gets.chomp.strip

    if (line.numeric?  )
        puts "Ok nice  "
        cond = true
     else 
        puts "Please enter number only  "
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 while cond == false
    if (line.numeric?  )
        puts "Ok nice  "
        cond = true
    else 
        puts "Please enter number only  "
        line = gets.chomp.strip
    end     
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Right after overriding String method, try this:

```
while true                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  print "Enter number "                                                                                                                                                                                           
  line = gets.chomp.strip

  if line.numeric?
    puts "Ok nice"
    break
  else
    puts "Please enter number only"
  end                                                                                                                                                                                        
end
```